# How to use the \n newline symbol in markdown to push text to next line?

Tags: markdown, zendesk

I'm about to submit an application to Zendesk, however, they require you to create a description for the application and they mention you can use Markdown to style it. The object I would submit with that information looks like this:

```
"app": {
    "name": "Application Name",
    "long_description": ""
}
```

And I need to set `long_description` to the Markdown. Now here's my issue - let's say I want the following 2 sentences like this:

```
Welcome to Application Name

Explanation about the application
```

I want them to have a new line between the 2 sentences and Zendesk says that I must use `\n` to achieve that, but they don't show any examples and there's no preview of how the application description would look like before uploading it, so I have to guess.

Do I need to set `long_description` to `"Welcome to Application Name\nExplanation about the application"` in order to achieve that space between the lines? I looked up Markdown's documentation and didn't really see `\n` symbol being used anywhere, so I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do I need to set long_description to "Welcome to Application Name\nExplanation about the application" in order to achieve that space between the lines?

Yes, that is probably correct. I think the thing you might be missing is that the `\n` is part of JSON, rather than markdown. So a JSON string like

```json
"Welcome to Application Name\nExplanation about the application"
```

gets translated into the markdown string

```
Welcome to Application Name
Explanation about the application
```

As a side note, you may need multiple `\n` characters between the two lines - some flavors of markdown treat a single line break as continuing the same line.

Answer (score 1):

Markdown uses the `<br>` tag from html instead of \n to start a new line, for example `Welcome to Application Name<br>Explanation about the application` which renders in the markdown editor's preview mode and on the webpage as follows.

Welcome to Application Name
Explanation about the application